# How to get all ints from inside a class instance?

Tags: python, types, python-2.x

I want to get all `int` types from a unknown class instance.

If I have the following class:

```
class myclass:
    g_goodies = 0
    g_stringer = "bob"
    mylist = []

    def __init__(self,goodies):
        self.g_goodies = goodies
        for x in range(0,10):
            self.mylist.append(0)
```

And I have tried...

```
def get_ints(self,inobject):
    a = inspect.getmembers(inobject)
    b = len(a)
    print 'a:',a,' b:',b
    print 'a type:',type(a),' b type:',type(b)
    for x in range(0,b-1):
        c = type(a[x])
        print c

print "Hello World!\n"
mc = myclass(10)
pa = printanything()
print pa.get_ints(mc)
```

Which gives me:

```
$python main.py
Hello World!

a: [('__doc__', None), ('__init__', <bound method myclass.__init__ of <__main__.myclass instance at 0x7f34ee9e80e0>>), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('g_goodies', 10), ('g_stringer', 'bob'), ('mylist', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]  b: 6
a type: <type 'list'>  b type: <type 'int'>
<type 'tuple'>
<type 'tuple'>
<type 'tuple'>
<type 'tuple'>
<type 'tuple'>
None
```

So I simply want to be able to extract all the type `int` in a class instance, all the type `str` in a class object, etc...  The class is not known at run time.

Comment: what I must add is this object does not have __dict__ as it is not descendent of object.

Comment: Could you give a specific example output for how it should turn out for your code? and also maybe fix your formatting?

Comment: You have some real indentation issues that you need to fix before we can answer this question.

Comment: Your unindented Python code is not a [mcve]

Comment: Stackoverflow wanted 4 spaces for the code... I know python wanted indentation spacing..

Comment: If the class is not known at run time then how on Earth can you inspect it? Also, is there some reason that you have to use old-style classes? They are rather limited compared to classes that inherit from `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You've left much out of your question, but here's a guess showing how to do something similar to what I think you'd like to do:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import inspect
from pprint import pprint, pformat


class MyClass:
    g_goodies = 0
    g_stringer = "bob"
    mylist = []

    def __init__(self,goodies):
        self.g_goodies = goodies
        for _ in range(10):
            self.mylist.append(0)


def get_ints(inobject):
    return [name for (name, value) in inspect.getmembers(inobject)
                if isinstance(value, int)]

mc = MyClass(10)
print(get_ints(mc))  # -> ['g_goodies']
```

Note that `mylist` isn't shown because it's a `list` not an `int`—but you *could* modify `get_ints()` to check the contents of any `list`s it encounters, too, if you wished.